# Programming Nxp NTag 213 using a smart card reader

Tags: java, nfc, smartcard, ndef, smartcard-reader

I would like to communicate with an NTag213 smarttag using an SCL010 smartcard reader. I looked into the **SCL010** manual and was able to read and write as a type 2 NFC tag as in case of Mifare tags but I have no knowledge of how to execute `FAST_READ`, `COMPATIBILITY_WRITE`, `READ_CNT`, `PWD_AUTH` and `READ_SIG` commands.

Comment: @NFC guy  Can you help me with this?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem.